# selecting a calendar dropdown in cypress

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-code, automation, cypress

i have a calendar widget in start date field. I would like to select the date in cypress using the cssSelector,how can we do that ?
The HTML is attached below for reference:

==$0

 
"Start Date"
*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to switch to calender window then you can select the date.
Below is the sample code snippet.

```
cy.get(startDate).click()//click start date
cy.get(calenderPopup)//it will read all dates in the calender
    .each(($el) => {
        var date = $el.text()
        if (today == date) {
            cy.wrap($el).click()
        }
    })
```